# Central Limit Theorem and sampling with 2 related random variable

Tags: sampling, central-limit-theorem

[image]

How can we apply central limit theorem to this question, since X and Y are related?

I'm doing a revision paper and think there might be something wrong with my approach.

I tried using

- T_bar=(200X+200Y)/200
- E(T_bar)=25+12=37
- Var(T_bar)=1/200^2 * (200(Var(x))+200 Var((y))+200 cov(x,y))

Comment: i realised there was a mistake in my var(T_bar), it should have been 1/200^2 * (200(Var(x))+200 Var((y))+400 cov(x,y))